# Flash builder variable from xml

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I would like to ask how to load variables from XML to flash builder. Is it possible? I think that I load variables, but my AS3 is done. I mean that variables from XML are loaded after doing script. Any idea how to do it? Thank for advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumming that you will have this xml (this code works perfectly):

```
<root>
<child id="1">
    <detail>
        <detailchild description="detail 1 child"/>
        <detailchild description="detail 2 child"/>
    </detail>
</child>
```

**OpenXml.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com

/flex/spark" firstView="views.OpenXmlHomeView" applicationDPI="160"> 
    </s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

**OpenXmlHomeView**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView" viewActivate="view_activateHandler()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            public function view_activateHandler():void{
                //Open a XML file
                var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../source.xml");
                ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
                ldr.load(request);              
            }

            private function onLoad(e:Event):void
            {
                var arr:Array = new Array();
                var ldr:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
                //XML was loaded then read 
                var myxml:XML = new XML(ldr.data);
                var xmlList:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(myxml.children());
                //Loop over XML childs to load a Question Array
                for each(var obj:Object in  xmlList){
                    arr.push(obj.@id);
                    var xmlChildren:XMLList = obj.detail;
                    for each (var qt:Object in new XMLListCollection(xmlChildren.children())){
                        arr.push(qt.@description);
                    }
                }
                lbl.text = arr.toString();

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="lbl" />
</s:View>
```

This code shows:

```
1, detail 1 child, detail 2 child
```

You can download this project **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5dwifcgq976tt37/OpenXml.fxp)**.

Note: This is a Flex Mobile project.

Answer (score 0):

Sample XML (message.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<category>
    <movie date = "13/07/31" genre = "Action">
    <title>foo</title>
    <rate>4.5</rate>
    </movie>
</category>
```

How to parsing XML to variables?

try this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class XML_Parsing_Tester extends Sprite
    {
        private var movieDate:String;
        private var movieGenre:String;
        private var movieTitle:String;
        private var movieRate:Number;

        public function XML_Parsing_Tester()
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(new URLRequest("message.xml"));
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        }

        private function onLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

            movieDate = xml.movie.@date;
            movieGenre = xml.movie.@genre;
            movieTitle = xml.movie.title;
            movieRate = xml.movie.rate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is it usable for Mobile apps? It gives me Errors "Classes must not be nested." and "The import ... is not used locally" for flash.net.URLLoader , flash.net.URLRequest, flash.display.Sprite .